# Hand generate views relationship

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

Here's the setup: the previous site builder linked a large quantity of assets to particular nodes.  Now that I'm on board, we want to expand those nodes into larger sections, but we need the linked assets to show up on all the pages.

Right now we have a view that uses a contextual filter to look at the NID.  Then, it refers to a relationship to see what assets are related to that NID.  Then, the view is filtered and displayed.

I need to come up with a way to display that same view on different pages that obviously don't share the same NID.  I've tagged all the pages within a section with the same taxonomy term.  I'd like to create a custom relationship that runs an equation that converts tid to nid.

> tid 62 = nid 15 
>   tid 63 = nid 47 
>   tid 64 = nid 153

I think you get the picture.  Any help?  If you have a better idea please let me know, thanks!
-JB

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ideas for you:

1) If there aren't too many nodes with assets - you could remove the contextual filter and create an "Or" Filter Group in the regular filter section of the view (based on NID). Then just list all of the NID's you want to filter by (NID 15 **Or** NID 47 **Or** NID153). That should pull in all of the assets from each of the Nodes without having to change the view much.

2) If you tagged the nodes containing the assets with taxonomy terms - you should also be able to use a regular taxonomy term filter instead of the contextual filter. I think in that case you would just need to add a **Content: Taxonomy terms on node relationship** to the view. That should open up a bunch of new taxonomy filter options in the regular filter section of views. You could then filter by term id or name.

You would just have to make sure you apply the **Content: Taxonomy terms on node relationship** to the term id filter when you set it up.